# Help identifying a varistor (on a shredder PCB)?

Tags: identification, varistor, mov

I am trying to identify what I think is a varistor. The markings are : "9 / MVG" and "10K431".

I think "10" is the diameter, "K" is the tolerance and "431" is voltage. Am I correct?

What does "9 / MVG" mean?

In reference to the the following sample part, how do I find out the "Clamping voltage", "Amperage" and "Capacitance" for the varistor I need to replace?

A sample part from RS:

> Vishay VDRS - E Series Metal Oxide Varistor
> 140pF 10A, Clamping 710V, Varistor 430V RS Stock No.178-071 Mfr. Part
> No.VDRS07H275BSE

The PCB I am trying to fix comes from a Fellowes 225i shredder.

[image: Damaged component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Varistor is a MYG-10K431.

The nomenclature that comes before the 'MYG', refers to the manufacturer, if I'm not mistaken.

The MYG-10K431 datasheet expose that:

Part Number Code: MYG-XXKXXX, wherein

- MYG : Product Type [9/MYG]
- XX  : Diameter     [05= 5mm; 07= 7mm; 10=10mm; 14=14mm; 20=20mm]
- K   : Tolerance    [K: (+ or -) 10%]
- XXXX: Voltage

So, I guess 9/MYG means the varistor type. Check the datasheet in the link bellow.

**Source [DATASHEET]:** https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1213341/ETC/MYG-10K431/1

Comment: Thank you very much.